# Aggregating/Paging through Twitter Search/Tweets 1.1 API ?

Tags: php, twitter

I would like to aggregate/page through the search tweets using the new [Search/Tweets v1.1 Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets). However, I can't understand how `since_id` and `max_id` works to do paging or get more tweets. Didn't get the idea of them.

Can anyone possibly do a simple example with some explanation? preferably in php.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Every tweet ever created is an incrementing value, each tweet from the API is assigned  `id_str`

This can be used as an ***offset*** for future requests

The value expected for `max_id` is the ***limit of the offset***

So imagine the latest tweet result from the API the `id_str` is: `345923546427568120`

Subtrack your tweets per page e.g 10 from that number and then do your next request with:

`since_id=345923546427568100&max_id=345923546427568110` **back 10 tweets**
`since_id=345923546427568090&max_id=345923546427568100` **back 20 tweets**
`since_id=345923546427568080&max_id=345923546427568090` **back 30 tweets**

The initial `345923546427568120` value can be set somewhere e.g session or a js var to go forward after going back some tweets, or better yet cache the result set for a short time.

Hope it helps

Comment: I don't think subtracting by 10 is correct. I've tried it and it gave me `Invalid Param` . What worked for me is using `max_id` alone as you said, saving it in a sessions and iterate each time.